# What is an indicator in statistics and why is it used to refine models?

Tags: self-study, model-selection, outliers

In a problem we are asked to "refine the fitted model by using an indicator for the outlier". What does it mean to use an indicator for an outlier?

Answer (score 3):

It means to introduce a predictor variable (explanatory variable, independent variable) which consists of a column of 0's, except for a 1 in the row where the outlier is.

The aim would be to estimate and thereby completely account for the size of the outlier by the coefficient of the dummy, removing its effect on the other coefficients.

I am not sure this has any value above simple deletion, except that your model explicitly shows what you did.

I don't know that it's always a wise thing to do, but some people do use deletion or dummy strategies for dealing with outliers, in such a fashion, so it's worth knowing about even if you don't generally use it.

There may well be some situations where it makes perfect sense to do this.

Comment: Indicators are not always 0/1 coded. They may also be any of a variety of contrast-coding methods (http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/library/contrast_coding.htm), or effect-coded (http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/faq/general/effect.htm). The latter is particularly important for avoiding heteroscedasticity pitfalls when modeling interaction terms.

Comment: @Alexis This is true (+1), but in the context of removing the effect of an outlier, I believe the idea will have been to simply use a 0/1 dummy: while any other pair of distinct values would do just as well at achieving that, the size of the outlier could at least be of some interest, and that's most directly achieved in the indicated fashion.